Can a drone fly forever?
I have an idea. If you attach some drones to a solar panel ( the big ones ) and use it to power the drones, can it fly forever? (Without weather) (With (not charged) extra batteries connected to the solar panel as input, drones as output)

The question is a little bit unclear at the moment. By "drone" are you talking about quadcopters, or just an unmanned aierial vehicle like a small fixed-wing aircraft?

Yes (sort of), but probably not the way you think.
The Airbus Zephyr, flies on solar, unmanned. Current record is 64 days and several thousand miles.
But with a wingspan (of the 8/S model) of 82 feet, it is the size of an airliner
